# is it possible for a pdf document to reduce embbedded images quality using a java library

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

Can we repack a pdf by reducing images' size(in bytes not dimensions) using itext or pdfbox or another java pdf library?

Comment: What you want is to compress every images in given pdf file ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614350/compress-pdf-with-large-images-via-java

Comment: Neither [tag:itext] nor [tag:pdfbox] do that out of the box but both can be used as PDF framework to retrieve the images, downsize them using an external library, and replace the original image with the downsized one.

Comment: You'll find a number of command-line tools that do this, if that is an option as well. Downsampling or recompressing images are standard functionality in most PDF preflight tools for example.