# How to change the filter of an image in a PDF file

Tags: java, image, pdf, pdfbox, jpeg2000

I'm building a tool to compress PDF files, and using pdfbox.
I have some images with the `DCTDecode` + `FlateDecode` filter and I'd like to experiment with the `JPXDecode` filter to see if it occupies less space.

I've seen some code using [`iText`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614350/compress-pdf-with-large-images-via-java), but how to do it with `pdfbox`?.  I've found no documentation how to do so.

Comment: I tried but failed: 1) Adobe doesn't accept my file 2) PDFBox displays it but the colors are wrong 3) I looked at the generated JPEG2000 image file and it looks terrible, the colors are wrong, I suspect that there is a bug in the encoder.

Comment: Thanks, then I wont have any other choice that to use `iText` or some other solution.

Comment: For what it is worth, from my experience, JPEG takes up less bytes for "small" images, while JPEG2000 provides better compression for "larger" images.

Comment: My PDF files are normally scanned pages, and are large.

Comment: Is there any sample on how to add the `FlateDecode` filter to an image?.  It seems to improve the compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `pdfbox` it is possible to compress all images, by using a custom `COSWriter` that handles all image streams and recodes them with the JPXDecode filter.  `pdfbox` isn't able to do so, but the JAI library with a plugin can generate a JPEG2000 image.  Compression factor is configurable, and high compression ratios can be achieved without losing too much quality.

By using in addition the `FlateDecode` filter, a little more compression can be obtained with no quality loss.

Answer (score 2):

This code replaces the image stream without having to alter COSWriter (which sounds scary), however my experience with the PDF I tried was that the encoded image was incorrect, i.e. that there is a bug in the JPEG 2000 encoder, so check your result PDFs.

```
public class SO57972743
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("supported formats: " + Arrays.toString(ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames()));

        try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("test.pdf")))
        {
            // get 1st level images only here (there may be more in form XObjects!)
            PDResources res = doc.getPage(0).getResources();
            for (COSName name : res.getXObjectNames())
            {
                PDXObject xObject = res.getXObject(name);
                if (xObject instanceof PDImageXObject)
                {
                    replaceImageWithJPX(xObject);
                }
            }
            doc.save("test-result.pdf");
        }
    }

    private static void replaceImageWithJPX(PDXObject xObject) throws IOException
    {
        PDImageXObject img = (PDImageXObject) xObject;
        BufferedImage bim = img.getOpaqueImage(); // the mask (if there) won't be touched
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        boolean written = ImageIO.write(bim, "JPEG2000", baos);
        if (!written)
        {
            System.err.println("write failed");
            return;
        }
        // replace image stream
        try (OutputStream os = img.getCOSObject().createRawOutputStream())
        {
            os.write(baos.toByteArray());
        }
        img.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.FILTER, COSName.JPX_DECODE); // replace filter
        img.getCOSObject().removeItem(COSName.COLORSPACE); // use the colorspace in the image itself
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't reemplement the full `COSWriter`, only derive from it and override the method that handles streams.
Your solution seems simpler than mine.